# sql inner join query

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

i am working on sql query please please check and give me the solution

please find the bellow task brief detail of tables

table 1  `'tbl_SuperAdmin'` having on filed

data like example

```
s_id name age gtc.......
1     abc  23 .........
2     cda  42 ..........
```

another table 2 having `'tbl_Renewal'`

```
renewalid  renname date supid   Payed etc......
1          first   -     1        1    ........
2          first   -     2        1    ........
3          second -      1        0     ........
4          second -      1        1     ........
5          third-        1        1     ........
```

query is  `select *from tbl_superadmin as a inner join tbl_Renewal as b on a.s_id=b.supid`

Result is

```
 s_id name age gtc....... renewalid  renname date supid   Payed etc.......
1     abc  23 .............1        first     -      1         1    ........
2     cda  42 .............2       first      -      2         1    ........
1     abc  23 .............3       second     -      1        0     ........
1     abc  23 .............4       second     -      1        1     ........
1     abc  23 .............5       third      -      1        1     ........
```

here i want how has payed=1 and renewalid desc and no need for s_id not repeat of 1 more the one time

i want to show my result like

```
  s_id name age gtc....... renewalid  renname date supid   Payed etc.......
    1     abc  23 .............5       third      -      1        1     ........ 
    2     cda  42 .............2       first      -      2         1    ........
```

like this result i want please any body help it

thanks 
pradeep

Comment: What did you try and where did that not work? StackOverflow is not meant as a 'please write my code for me!' place, but as a place where you can learn. Please add your own code for us to see :-)

Comment: It will also help if you provide explicit table structures (instead of just data examples). You can edit your own question by clicking the _edit_ button at the bottom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the duplicates you need to use [Windows Function](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/).

```
With cte as 
(
 select *,row_number() over(partition by s_id order by renewalid desc )rn
 from tbl_superadmin as a 
 inner join tbl_Renewal as b 
 on a.s_id=b.supid
)
Select * from cte where rn=1
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1f7f/2)

**Update**

```
;With cte as 
( 
 select *,row_number() over(partition by s_id order by renewalid desc )rn 
 from alz_SuperAdmin as a inner join alz_Renewal as b on a.s_id=b.supid
)
select top 2 CONVERT(varchar(6),a.lastdate,6) as lastdate,
(select name from alz_states where ID=a.joblocation ) as locat,
from alz_jobpost as a
inner join 
(Select col1,col2,col3.... from cte where rn=1 )ct
on ct.commonColumn=a.CommonColumn  and 
ct.Product in 
(Select query)
```

Comment: Hai praveen see this problem also .............................select top 2  CONVERT(varchar(6),a.lastdate,6) as lastdate,(select name from alz_states where ID=a.joblocation ) as locat,* from alz_jobpost as a inner join (With cte as ( select  *,row_number() over(partition by s_id order by renewalid desc )rn  from alz_SuperAdmin as a  inner join alz_Renewal as b  on a.s_id=b.supid)Select * from cte where rn=1 and cte.product in (select [plan]  from alz_features where Fjobs=1) and c.Payed=1) as aa on a.oid=aa.businessid

Comment: The query doesn't seems correct.You cannot use `CTE ` in a `sub query`

Comment: nice if suppose we can user more than inner join to the with statement what is the result is showing

Comment: Please check my updated answer .However im  still not clear about your query . `cte.product in
   (select [plan] from alz_features where Fjobs=1) and c.Payed=1) as aa on a.oid=aa.businessid` doesn't make sense as in your select query you are not selecting `businessid` but still you are referncing in your join condition .It will be better if you post a new question with all the details

Comment: The result is string like:------"Premium,hitech,beasc " here this error is showing :----------  Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'PREMIUM' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a GROUP BY and ORDER in your query. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_SuperAdmin AS a
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Renewal AS b 
ON 
    a.s_id = b.supid
GROUP BY
    a.s_id
ORDER BY
    b.renewalid
DESC
```

Comment: this one is showing this error Column 'tbl_SuperAdmin.S_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.